# add-apt-repository returns unexpected length error

Tags: add-apt-repository

Ubuntu 11.10 (oneiric ocelot):
When I try to add a new ppa through add-apt-repository, it returns with:

```
rene@rene-MS-N104:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 88, in <module>
    ppa info = get_ppa_info_from_lp(usr, ppa_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 80, in get_ppa_info_from_lp
    curl.perform()
pycurl.error(35, 'gnutls_handshake() failed: A TLS packet with unexpected length was recieved.')
```

I'm fairly new to Ubuntu and am not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It appears this is a [known issue/bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pycurl/+bug/926548), you could try this workaround:

To install PPA's, add them to `/etc/apt/sources.list` in the form:

Before:

```
ppa:<user>/<repo>
```

Add to `sources.list`:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/<user>/<repo>/ubuntu oneiric main
```

Then `sudo apt-get update` and download whatever packages you want.

Comment: Is there any system way to solve this question? Thank you~

Comment: You will have to upgrade to 12.10

Answer (score 2):

In my case,and that worked, that's what I did in Ubuntu 12.04:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

And then I tried to add my ppa as usual :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:.../...
```

Hopes it works for everyone !

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I was using the WiFi. But then I tried with my mobile broadband connection which uses automatic PPP and it worked fine. I am not sure but it may be to do with opening of port 11371 in the router of WiFi.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following URL for the solution.

https://gnutls-help.gnutls.narkive.com/sqMssk7Q/big-ca-certificate-bundle-causes-problems-with-gnutls-3-0-11

Quoted from [one of the comments](https://gnutls-help.gnutls.narkive.com/sqMssk7Q/big-ca-certificate-bundle-causes-problems-with-gnutls-3-0-11#post5) in the link.

> A quick solution to avoid this issue is to restrict the CAs that you
> enable to the server to the minimum required (a typical server needs
> to trust only the authorities that signed the user's certificates).

Comment: Linking external sites as an answer is never recommended, preferably you should copy the important information that you think might be helpful and leave a link to the source. One link answers are not good answers.