# How do I add the "gnome-shell-extensions" PPA?

Tags: 12.04, apt, ppa

When I'm trying to add **any** ppa using "apt" I get the following error:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome-shell-extensions

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 125, in <module>
    ppa_info = get_ppa_info_from_lp(user, ppa_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 80, in get_ppa_info_from_lp
    curl.perform()
pycurl.error: (7, "couldn't connect to host")
```

Nevertheless, apt is working fine and I can install/remove/upgrade applications, moreover curl is also OK I've already checked it... My internet connection is also fine, I can use any application using internet. I am not behind any proxies or firewalls.

Everything was working fine before I updated from Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04.

**BTW:** I know i can add an entry manually, but such situation is really annoying.
I've been googling for a long time but with no result :(

Any ideas? Thanks :)

Comment: Try the first and second comments in this AskUbuntu [thread](http://askubuntu.com/questions/110672/add-apt-repository-returns-unexpected-length-error). I know it's for 11.10, but I had the same issue and used this workaround.

Comment: You need to add DNS nameserver in Network Manager  as here http://askubuntu.com/questions/131982/i-cant-add-ppa-repositories, and to Mods possible duplicate.

Comment: As far i see u had problems with dns pycurl.error: (6, ...). It's all different here i think :( No workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

OK! So now, there's a brilliant explanation to all of this mess!
I don't know how and why, but after installing ubuntu 12.04, gnome sets proxy to some applications using say... ftp, eg. Now, run gconf-editor and go system->proxy and remove all of the proxy entries. It should do :) I know it's stupid to answer my own question anyway maybe it'll be useful for the others :) cheers!

Comment: It's not stupid to answer your own question. [It's most excellent.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Answer (score 0):

When adding a PPA with `sudo add-apt-repository` you need to specify the whole adr. ess. So in your case it would be `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:LP-NAME/PPA-NAME`.

In your example you forgot the name of the user.

Comment: Yeah, it's obvious it was a bad example. Anyway, to make it clear -  when i'm trying to add eg. ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa the same thing happens, so it's not a case.