# install android sdk on kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, android

I'm trying to follow the instructions for installing the android sdk found here:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html

After I've unpackaged and i run the android program under tools, I don't get all the options that I'm supposed to.  The only 2 folders that show up are tools, and extras.  Under tools, it only shows the "Android SDK Tools" with the status "Installed".  Under the "extras" folder, I have nothing. 
I've made sure that my http: proxy settings are correct. 
And I've checked the logs. there are no errors.
According to the android developer site, I'm supposed to install the SDK platform tools.

has anyone tried this on Ubuntu? I also checked and saw others were instructed to do an apt-get install ia32-libs but it failed for me.  Besides which, I am running the 32bit OS... so I don't think i would need to install that... ??

I've also tried following the instructions found here:

http://forums.team-nocturnal.com/showthread.php/772

But... I can't seem to add the personal archive nilarimogard without getting an error message.
when i attempt:

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
```

I get the message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 125, in <module>
ppa_info = get_ppa_info_from_lp(user, ppa_name)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 80,
in get_ppa_info_from_lp
curl.perform() pycurl.error: (7, "couldn't connect to host") root@jll:/home/me/Documents#
```

any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I just followed a previous post with a similar issue: askubuntu.com/questions/110672/… and it worked.  I did get a the following warning:

> Reading package lists... Done W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net
>   oneiric Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because
>   the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 531EE72F4C9D234C

but it seems to get the java updates.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that SDK installs on Ubuntu/Kubuntu without a problem, I did that more than once. You don't need any third-party PPAs for that.

Are you going to use Eclipse (you should)? If so, I suggest to skip this step and just start with installing ADT plugin as described [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html) - it will download all necessary stuff in the process.

If you're behind a proxy see Troubleshooting section at the bottom of the page

Comment: I don't have Eclipse... I will check into it.  I'm just new to kubuntu.  But i don't actually plan on writing andriod stuff.  i just want to install an emulator so i can test a website that I've built.  Need to make sure it scales properly on a mobile device.  Would you still recommend that i install the sdk and eclipse?

Comment: I just followed a previous post with a similar issue:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/110672/add-apt-repository-returns-unexpected-length-error and it worked.