# "error: gnutls_handshake() failed" when connecting to https servers

Tags: git

When I try to connect to any HTTPS server with `git`, it gives the following error:

```
error: gnutls_handshake() failed: A TLS packet with unexpected length was received. while accessing ...
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

I think that maybe some packages that are related to `gnutls_handshake` have been broken. So, I want to reinstall those.

Which packages can be related to these errors? Or how do I fix this kind of error?

Comment: This [other question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/110672/add-apt-repository-returns-unexpected-length-error) might help.

Comment: In my case it was a simple authentication server, to which we have to login before using the internet, which was coming in the way. I had to login there first, and then the error vanished.

Answer (score 99):

Got reason of the problem, it was `gnutls` package. It's working weird behind a proxy. But `openssl` is working fine even in weak network. So workaround is that we should compile `git` with `openssl`. To do this, run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential fakeroot dpkg-dev
sudo apt-get build-dep git
mkdir ~/git-openssl
cd ~/git-openssl
apt-get source git
dpkg-source -x git_1.7.9.5-1.dsc
cd git-1.7.9.5
```

(Remember to replace `1.7.9.5` with the actual version of git in your system.)

Then, edit `debian/control` file (run the command: `gksu gedit debian/control`) and replace all instances of `libcurl4-gnutls-dev` with `libcurl4-openssl-dev`.

Then build the package (if it's failing on test, you can remove the line `TEST=test` from the file `debian/rules`):

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
sudo dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -b
```

Install new package:

i386:  `sudo dpkg -i ../git_1.7.9.5-1_i386.deb`

x86_64: `sudo dpkg -i ../git_1.7.9.5-1_amd64.deb`

---

Inspired from here: https://github.com/xmendez/wfuzz/wiki/PyCurlSSLBug

Comment: Had this same issue after upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04. This solution worked great!

Comment: Worked with Linux Mint 16, you have to go to "Software Sources" and enable sources on official repositories. You must also uninstall libcurl4-gnutls-dev and replace by libcurl4-openssl-dev prior to compiling.

Comment: Might help the wondering minds. If you're using 'repo' to download a repository (say android source code) and come across the gnutls-handshake problem, @Nyambaa's answer works. Repo is a script which depends on Git, so you should be good. Worked like magic on my Ubuntu 14.04 lts

Comment: This also worked to solve my Android repo sync problem that was resulting in `error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200`.

Comment: Shellscript for people's (mainly my own) sanity. https://github.com/SonOfLysander/git-openssl-shellscript/blob/master/git-openssl.sh

Comment: Never seen an example like this. Worked like a charm! :D

Comment: I wonder, if my Mac OS X git version could be fixed similarly. But at least I now can use git from my Ubuntu VM with my strange remote https repository that tries to be very safe. Thanks.

Comment: @BCqrstoO in shellscript `find .. -type f -name "git_*ubuntu*.deb" -exec sudo dpkg -i \{\} \;` is overboard... `sudo dpkg -i ../git_*.deb` is more then sufficient.

Comment: @kevinf Thanks for that tip! I had recently found out how to use the find command properly, and I went a bit overboard with it. I'll fix it up :)

Comment: the tests in the build step take a really long time. if you trust the git maintainers, I highly suggest following the instructions above to skip them by removing the TEST=test line from debian/rules.

Comment: Fix worked for me. Be sure to add the git-core ppa to /etc/apt/sources.list if it does not exist. https://launchpad.net/~git-core/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Comment: @nyambaa I am getting error in last step :( 

`sudo dpkg -i ../git_2.7.4.0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
dpkg: error processing archive ../git_2.7.4.0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ../git_2.7.4.0ubuntu1_amd64.deb`

Comment: `apt-get install` returns: `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dpkg-dev : Depends: libdpkg-perl (= 1.17.5ubuntu5.7) but 1.18.18 is to be installed` - what you can recommend? 14.04 with all updates.

Comment: You have to install `libcurl4-openssl-dev` before running `sudo dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -b`

Comment: what is source in apt-get source git command ?

Comment: After all that (which worked) I still get that failure ` gnutls_handshake() failed: Error in the pull function`

Comment: work like a charm!

Comment: u had this issue on 18.04, it turns out I changed the log in password. I just reboot the machine.

Comment: `sudo dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -b` took so much time. anyways, it works. Thanks

Comment: On Windows Bash (WSL), the ```sudo dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -b``` step fails with a message ```fakeroot: error while starting the `faked' daemon.```.  This [link](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/2132) recommends running ```sudo update-alternatives --set fakeroot /usr/bin/fakeroot-tcp```

Answer (score 9):

For me, it ended up being that SSL certificate was self-signed. Give this a try

`git config --global http.sslVerify false`

Comment: That's a terrible idea; it disables _all_ authentication for _every_ TLS (SSL) connection made by `git`, removing your protection from man-in-the-middle attacks.

Answer (score 1):

This is mentioned in one of the [comments to another answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186847/error-gnutls-handshake-failed-when-connecting-to-https-servers/187199#comment949926_187199) but I feel it needs to be more visible https://askubuntu.com/users/177551/paul-nelson-baker has written a shell script which, for me, resolved this issue.

The script is available in his repository https://github.com/paul-nelson-baker/git-openssl-shellscript and re-compiles git with openssl instead of gnutls. Read the README for the whole story but it worked for me so thank you Paul.

Comment: the link is dead and thus this answer is not useful at all

Comment: @eis For me each of the three links in the answer are working as I type. Perhaps you could explain which link you're referring to when you "the link" ? Thanks.

Comment: the shellscript link, which this answer is about. Seems to work for me now as well, didn't work yesterday for some reason. However, this answer is a link-only answer regardless, so it would be good to have some contents in the answer for the case that link would stop working.