# Error downloading ubuntu touch sources, GnuTLS recv error (-9) and SSL read errno 104

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android, git

I am downloading the required android sources https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/porting-new-device to be able to port ubuntu touch to a new device and ... I am running into quite a bit of issues.

- While running the phablet-dev-bootstrap phablet command I got the error: **GnuTLS recv error (-9)**, I "fixed" this issue following this guide: ["error: gnutls_handshake() failed" when connecting to https servers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186847/error-gnutls-handshake-failed-when-connecting-to-https-servers/187199#187199)
- But then I got this error: **SSL read errno 104** from using Libcurl4-openssl-dev, it seemed quite erratic (sometimes it could download a couple of gb and sometimes it would crash after a few hundred mb).
- So I wrote a little bash script to restart upon errors to see how far could I get, to see if it could download the whole >15GB by retrying multiple times.
- After a few days, I am at 17GB and is not done (I though it was 15 GB, I am close I guess) but now I am stuck, the **SSL read errno 104** comes every time while fetching the project: *aosp/platform/frameworks/base* and I am out of ideas.

I have tried a few other things and spent a few days iterating without luck (frustrating...), Does anyone know of a way that I can fix the **SSL read errno 104** issue to complete the download?

Comment: Arrrgh actually, it seems my router might be misbehaving. I set up a set of little experiments to figure out what the problem really was... and it seems I can connect from other places but when I do it through the house router (DIR-601 E1)  it fails ... this model also seems to have quite a bit of bad rep so I think I might have found the culprit... I will post an update in a few days.