# Occasional gnutls handshake error

Tags: git, windows-subsystem-for-linux, gnutls

I'm trying to download the AOSP from Google using `repo sync`. Occasionally, I receive an error similar to the following:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/bt/': gnutls_handshake() failed: Error in the push function.
```

I tried the solution posted ["error: gnutls_handshake() failed" when connecting to https servers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186847/error-gnutls-handshake-failed-when-connecting-to-https-servers). Unfortunately, it ended with openssl not functioning properly in WSL. So, I uninstalled that build of `git` and reinstalled `sudo apt-get install git`. My current git version is 2.7.4.

**The error appears only occasionally,** e.g. the first `repo sync` checked out 90% of the projects successfully. Here is a screenshot illustrating the erratic behavior of the error:
[image]

Lastly, I am using WSL with a proxy so there is plenty of room for strange issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, my proxy resolved to 1 of 2 IP addresses. One of them worked without issue, the other did not.