# Not able to clone git repository in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: server, permissions, 20.04, git

After upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04, I am not able to clone git repository in Ubuntu 20.04.

```
Cloning into 'distributed-architecture-cache'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/M-Thirumal/distributed-architecture-cache.git/': 

gnutls_handshake() failed: Access was denied
```

Any help?

```
thirumal@thirumal:~$ nmap -p 443 --script ssl-cert github.com
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-05-05 13:38 IST
Nmap scan report for github.com (13.234.176.102)
Host is up (0.018s latency).
rDNS record for 13.234.176.102: ec2-13-234-176-102.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com

PORT    STATE SERVICE
443/tcp open  https
| ssl-cert: Subject: commonName=github.com/organizationName=GitHub, Inc./stateOrProvinceName=California/countryName=US
| Subject Alternative Name: DNS:github.com, DNS:www.github.com
| Issuer: commonName=DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA/organizationName=DigiCert Inc/countryName=US
| Public Key type: rsa
| Public Key bits: 2048
| Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
| Not valid before: 2018-05-08T00:00:00
| Not valid after:  2020-06-03T12:00:00
| MD5:   9c81 f7d7 ad12 6a83 217b 35ac 5dc7 aa02
|_SHA-1: ca06 f56b 258b 7a0d 4f2b 0547 0939 4786 5115 1984

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.92 seconds
```

Comment: Is it only this git or any git repository? Please add the output of `nmap -p 443 --script ssl-cert github.com`. Are you behind a corporate firewall or proxy ?

Comment: Same error for both github and bitbucket. No I am not behind any firewall.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["error: gnutls\_handshake() failed" when connecting to https servers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186847/error-gnutls-handshake-failed-when-connecting-to-https-servers)

Comment: That's not helpful

Comment: I've got the same issue on a fresh install of focal fossa (mate flavour). The suggestion about credential.helper doesn't help. Kinda running out of ideas. The only thing I can think of is that some 3rs party package installed libssl1.0.0 and that screwed something up. But I've purged that now, so should not affect things anymore. Anybody got any other ideas?

Comment: FYI I am getting the same error on Focal if I configure an HTTPS-based APT repository (eg https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-bionic main). This is very annoying... This even happens when using the *Ubuntu 20.04 Live ISO*...

And it's not some anti-virus or network thing: a different VM running Linux Mint 19.2 works fine. Web browsers (Chrome, Firefox) don't seem affected either.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this command `git config --system --unset credential.helper` which resets your credentials for git. 
It seems to be a permission issue.