# Cannot Add PPA Behind Proxy Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ppa, 14.04, proxy, add-apt-repository

I am unable to add a repository via the command line on Ubuntu 14.04. Apt-get works perfectly fine, and I am able to update the system. I have configured my /etc/apt/apt.config file as follows:

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://<username>:<password>@<proxy address>:<port>/";
```

For example, when trying to add the repository for y-ppa-manager, I receive:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.
```

If you need any more info., feel free to ask.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You need to export your proxy environment variables using

```
export http_proxy=http://username:password@host:port/
export https_proxy=https://username:password@host:port/
```

and then tell sudo to use them using:

```
 sudo -E add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
```

or open your `/etc/sudoers` file (using `sudo visudo`) and append

```
Defaults env_keep="https_proxy"
```

to the end of the file.

I have [a blog on this](http://thelittleican.blogspot.in/2013/09/unable-to-add-ppa-behind-proxy.html), have a look at it for more details.

Comment: Thank you so much Jobin for the prompt reply! I used Method 1 from your blog, so I don't have to remember the "-E" each time.

Comment: In my case the problem was solved by this method: http://askubuntu.com/questions/355729/cant-add-any-ppas

I mention this because it was not so easy to find in google (in my case the results point to this kind of solutions).

Comment: `alias sudo=sudo -E`