# RabbitCVS no context menus in Nautilus

Tags: nautilus, menu, rabbitvcs

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and have installed RabbitVCS via the synaptic package manager (rabbitvcs-cli, rabbitvcs-gedit and rabbitvcs-nautilus).  The nautilus file manager is showing icons on the appropriate folders but there is no SVN menu when I right click the folders.  I have rebooted.
I have searched and worked on this problem for some time now and I am no further along.  One suggestion was to install rabbitVCS via the PPA but I am having problems doing that because I am behind a proxy server and I can't seem to access the keyserver - that is another problem I spent quite some time on!
Does anybody have any suggestions for me?  Am fairly amateur at ubuntu so not sure where to go from here. 
Thanks.

Comment: Did you have a look at [this](askubuntu.com/questions/346602/13-04-no-context-menu-after-rabbitvcs-install) or [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/452595/cannot-add-ppa-behind-proxy-ubuntu-14-04/452601#452601)

Comment: Thank you!  Your links lead me to the fix at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rabbitvcs/+bug/1093533